# jQuery: check / uncheck checkboxes

Tags: jquery, checkbox, each

I have two divs. Div A and Div B. Div A contains anchors when you click on one it displays a list of checkboxes that i get from an array in Div B. I have a limit, a user can only choose three checkboxes from all the lists that he can get by clicking on anchors.

I have a limit if more than 2 then unchecked checkboxes are being disabled.

```
if (countShownCats > -1 && countShownCats < 3) {
     // Enable checkboxes
     $('.rbSubcategoryList input:checkbox:not(:checked)').attr('disabled', false);
  } else {
     // Disable non checked checkboxes
     $('.rbSubcategoryList input:checkbox:not(:checked)').attr('disabled', true);
  }
```

When i click on an anchor and it appends a list of checkboxes, checkboxes are not checked. Here's the code:

```
$('.rbSubcategoryList input[value="' + rbCheckboxValue + '"]').attr('checked', true);
```

But only first checkbox that was clicked is getting checked. I know that I have to use $.each somehow, but can't figure out how.

So my question is how do i make it work so all three checkboxes that are checked remain checked when i click on the anchor?

Thank you!

Comment: please share jsfiddle link

Comment: For some reason this function `$('.rbSubcategoryList input:checkbox').live('change', function () {` doesn't work in jsfiddle. This is the part that adds blocks to Div C. Here's the link: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/alexchizhov/T5858/)

Comment: use `.on()` instead of `.live()`, as `.live()` will not work for jquery more than 1.6

Comment: `.live()` works for me on a website, `.on()` doesn't work on a website, neither on jsfiddle :/

Comment: what is the jquery version you are using?

Comment: See this http://api.jquery.com/live/ ... it says it is deprecated in 1.7 and removed from 1.9 version. Then how come it is working in 1.11.0... I think you should verify your version and check if there is no other jquery library include which is less than 1.7 version.

Comment: `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>` this is the only place where i include jquery on the page.

Comment: `.live` is there in `http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js` .. try to include it in jsfiddle using external resources.

Comment: [jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/alexchizhov/T5858/2/) Thank you, categories are now being add to Div C. But still cant  figure out the main problem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, think I've got it now.

You were not looping through the hidden inputs in `.rbWwCatPicked` which is why only one check box was checked.

```
   $('.rbWwCatPicked input[type=hidden]').each(function(){
       $('.rbSubcategoryList input[value="' + $(this).data('pickedcat-hidden') + '"]').prop('checked', true);
   });
```

and the updated fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/T5858/17/

---

Sorry didn't read the question properly.

Try this out:

```
$('.rbSubcategoryList').click(function () {
  var c = $(this).find('input:checkbox:checked').length;
  if (c >= 2) {
    $(this).find('input:checkbox:not(:checked)').prop('disabled', true);
  } else {
    $(this).find('input:checkbox:not(:checked)').prop('disabled', false);
  }
});
```

Here's the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/p8zZu/

It seems there are some issues with your JavaScript as well. Check the errors logged in the console of your browser.

---

If I understand correctly, you're asking for assistance with the use of the `each` method?

Try

```
$('.rbSubcategoryList input[value="' + rbCheckboxValue + '"]').each(function () {
  $(this).prop('checked', true);
});
```

Comment: thank you, thats a good peace of code :) any way, its not the main problem. If take a look at my link here [http://jsfiddle.net/alexchizhov/T5858/4/](http://jsfiddle.net/alexchizhov/T5858/4/). When you click on a checkbox in `.rbSubcategoryList` it appends an orange block below. So when I click 3 checkboxes, all checkboxes that are not checked are being disabled. But when I click an anchor in the first block, all of them are being unchecked again. It only checks first checkbox that was clicked. And I need script to check all three, when i click on an anchor in the first block :)